# Sequence contains no elements? error for one category but no error for another category in same view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Please see my controller and view below. I dont get the error for Category 2 but I get error for category 4 Why do I get this error? I have followed the error with breakpoint. Product list comes from controller. there is problem in foreach loop. Thanks for your helps.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> Products = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.LineNumber).Where(x=>x.IsActive==true).ToList();

        ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        return View(Products);
    }
```

My view

```
    <div class="container-index-section">
        @foreach (Product item in Model.Where(x => x.Category.Name == 2))
        {
            <div class="container-index-category-product-@item.Size">
                <div class="container-index-category-product">
                    <a href="~/Home/ProductDetail/@item.Id"><img src="~/ProductPhotos/Normal/@item.Photos.First().PhotoPath" alt="" style="width:65%" /></a>
                    <h2 style="color:orange">@item.DiscountedPrice <span style="font-size:smaller">TL</span></h2>
                    <p style="color:black">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ProductDetail", new { id = item.Id })</p>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart","Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Sepete Ekle</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container-index-section-clear">

    </div>

    <div class="container-index-section">


        @foreach (Product item in Model.Where(x => x.Category.Id == 4))
        {
            <div class="container-index-category-product-@item.Gender">
                <div class="container-index-category-product">
                    <a href="~/Home/ProductDetail/@item.Id"><img src="~/ProductPhotos/Normal/@item.Photos.First().PhotoPath" alt="" style="width:65%" /></a>
                    <h2 style="color:orange">@item.DiscountedPrice <span style="font-size:smaller">TL</span></h2>
                    <p style="color:black">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ProductDetail", new { id = item.Id })</p>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart","Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Sepete Ekle</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }



    </div>
```

Comment: You should better tag this with what MVC framework you are using.

Comment: on which exactly line you getting error?

Comment: I get the error the next line with the curly brakets after second foreach line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `item.Photos` might be an empty collection and your code assumes that it has atleast one item.

Adding an if condition to check the existence of at least one item before accessing the first item will fix the error.

```
<a href="~/Home/ProductDetail/@item.Id">
  @if(item.Photos.Any())
  {
     <img src="~/ProductPhotos/Normal/@item.Photos.First().PhotoPath"
                                                          alt="" style="width:65%" />
  }
</a>
```